# .Net Windows Service Memory Usage

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, windows-services, wsdl

I have a windows service codded with C#. 
It has only a job : it calls a wsdl web service every 30 seconds and doesn't save any data in memory.
But, after a few weeks, it uses nearly 1gb system memory. It doesn't store any data in memory and i run GC every 1 minutes.
Why can it use so high memory?

This is my code sample :

```
//this function is called by System.Timers.Timer 
    static bool GenerateAndSendXML(string agentName)
            {
                bool status = false;
                try
                {

                    string xmlMsg = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" +
                                         @"<test>
                                        <SignalType>StatusSignal</SignalType>
                                        <AgentName>" + agentName.Trim() + @"</AgentName>

                                </test>";
                    var ir = new StatusSoapClient();//WSDL service
                    XmlElement xml = ir.ImportXml(xmlMsg);

                    string ReturnCode = "", ExpMessage = "";

                    for (int i = 0; i < xml.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (xml.ChildNodes[i].Name == "ReturnCode") ReturnCode = xml.ChildNodes[i].InnerText.ToUpperInvariant().ToString();
                        if (xml.ChildNodes[i].Name == "ExpMessage") ExpMessage = xml.ChildNodes[i].InnerText.ToUpperInvariant().ToString();

                    }


                    if (ReturnCode == "1")
                        status = true;
                    else
                        status = false;
                    Functions.WriteServiceLog(xmlMsg, ReturnCode, ExpMessage);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Functions.WriteErrorLog(ex);//nlog function
                }

                return status;
            }
```

Thanks,

Comment: are  you releasing your object properly...

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: @seckin - close your WCF client that will release your objects which is not in use

Answer (score 1):

I dont know what actully going wrong but if you client calling wcf service than you should code it as below , means make use of using keyword to drop object properly

```
 using (CalculatorClient client = new CalculatorClient())
        {
            // Call Divide and catch the associated Exception.  This throws because the
            // server aborts the channel before returning a reply.
            try
            {
                client.Divide(0.0, 0.0);
            }
            catch (CommunicationException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Got {0} from Divide.", e.GetType());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this method call put xmlMsg in some collection?

```
Functions.WriteServiceLog(xmlMsg, ReturnCode, ExpMessage);
```

Comment: I suspect this method may be holding a refernce to xmlMsg which is preventing it from getting garbage collected.